Images display the same url as the first, when it should display dynamically (Simple jQuery)
I'm trying to make the src attribute of each image converted into an href, I'm almost there, but only the first image is displayed in the href link of the others, when each one should display its own href based on its src attribute, see below:
<div class="images">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400">
</div>

jQuery(function($) {
var src = $(".images img").attr('src');
$('.images img').wrap('<a href="' + src + '"/>');
});

jsfiddle
I tried some combinations, but none of them gave me the solution.
